# Trouble with a relative import and pytest

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest, python-import

I'm working on a Python 2 project and having trouble with a relative import. I've got a package that's a sibling to the main code, with it's own structure. I'm writing tests for this package, but it requires importing a module from the main code, so when I run pytest, I get `ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package.` Ironically, I don't even need the package for the tests; I'm mocking the only method that uses them (it's a DB variable).

It's importing as `from ....serenity.util.io import postgres_db_engine`. Any ideas on what I can do to get around this?

Comment: Please add the code here.

Comment: Which part of the code? I'm not positive what's relevant to helping figure the problem out.

Comment: I guess it is something related with syspath. Are you using IDE like Pycharm?

Comment: Yah, I'm using Pycharm @Raguel

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I'll think about how I can make a minimal reproduceable example, not sure how to in this sort of file linking setup.

Comment: have you tried running `pytest` from the terminal instead of through the IDE?

Comment: It is being run through the terminal